# The subcontent is added 2 times, in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using symfony 2, and i'm really stuck with this. I have a content entity, and a subcontent entity. I want to show **both entities**. And this part is working, I can fetch the right subcontents and they are added to the right content. But they are **added 2 times in a content**. I dont understand why. The subcontents are always **duplicated**. Here is the code where they are added, this is in the ContentController.

```
$contents = $em->getRepository('myBundle:Content')->findAll();

   foreach($contents as $cont){
        $subcont = $em->getRepository('myBundle:SubContent')->findByContent( $cont->getId());

        foreach($subcont as $sb){
             $cont->addSubcontent( $sb );
        }
    }
```

Maybe is a simple thing, but i dont see it. Can anyone help me with this, or show me another way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Doctrine (ORM used in Symfony2 by default) already does what you do automatically, so you are actually duplicating subcontent instances in your content.

To see it's already there you can do:

```
$contents = $em->getRepository('myBundle:Content')->findAll();

foreach ($contents as $content) {
    foreach ($content->getSubcontents() as $subcontent) {
        var_dump($subcontent);
    }
}
```

Doctrine uses technique called `lazy loading`. That means, when you load a `Content` entity from your database and than you do `$content->getSubcontents()`, it will automatically do a query against database which will load it's subcontents and return them to you.

However, since this might fire many queries if you use it in foreach loop you should probably tell it to join subcontents directly in query.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I have seen lazy loading technique, but didn't understand it very well. I solved my problem, with only one foreach, the data its not duplicated now.

Answer (score 1):

You search Subcontent by contentId : that means that you've already linked sub content to content.
But why are you linking then again with **$cont->addSubcontent( $sb );** ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, wasn't getting that doctrine does it all automatically.